# Chaining maps increasing list nesting level

Tags: python, scheme, nested-loops, nested-lists, map-function

I'm trying to do the follow Python conversion to Scheme to practice nested looping:

```
>>> def possible_triads(n1, n2, n3):
        for num1 in n1:
             for num2 in n2:
                 for num3 in n3:
                     print (num1, num2, num3)
```

```
>>> possible_triads([1,2], [3,4], [5,6])
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
(1, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 6)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 3, 6)
(2, 4, 5)
(2, 4, 6)
```

Here is my attempt to do it in Scheme:

```
(define (possible-triads n1 n2 n3)
  (map (lambda (num1)
         (map (lambda (num2)
                (map (lambda (num3) (list num1 num2 num3)) 
                     n3)) 
              n2)) 
       n1))
```

```
(possible-triads '(1 2) '(3 4) '(5 6))
;((((1 3 5) (1 3 6)) ((1 4 5) (1 4 6))) (((2 3 5) (2 3 6)) ((2 4 5) (2 4 6))))
```

Now, it's close, but I'm wondering why each `map` produces a new level of listing? For example, how can I get the results to just be a list of triplets, such as:

```
(
    (1 3 5) 
    (1 3 6)
    (1 4 5)
    (1 4 6)
    (2 3 5)
    (2 3 6)
    (2 4 5)
    (2 4 6)
)
```

Comment: `map` makes a list of its results. The Python version doesn't make a list at each level, it just iterates.

Comment: The Python version isn't putting its results anywhere, it's just printing.

Comment: The Scheme version is analogous to nested list comprehensions in Python.

Comment: @Barmar so would I need to do something like: `(set! L (append L (list (list num1 num2 num3)))))` to create a list of the 3-tuples?

Comment: @Barmar how like a list comprehension, that doesn't produce additional levels of nesting, for example: `>>> [(num1, num2, num3) for num1 in [1,2] for num2 in [3,4] for num3 in [5,6]]`
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6)]

Comment: You should be using `for-each` rather than `map`, and then use `display` in the innermost loop.

Comment: @Barmar oh I see, I don't know that construction yet (still on the second chapter of sicp...) so really only know about using `map` or recursion for doing for-ish loops.

Comment: No, it's like nested list comprehensions. `[[[(num1, num2, num3) for num3 in n3] for num2 in n2] for num1 in n1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to try to take some code from an Algol-like language like Python and to "translate" it into lispy code. As mentioned by [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67844814/6879826), the Python code is not creating a list of results, it is only printing the results as a side-effect; the Scheme code is actually creating a list of results. The problem in the posted code is that the innermost `map` creates a list of lists, the intermediate `map` creates another list of lists from that, and the outermost `map` creates yet another list of lists from the nested lists it receives.

You can make this work by strategically appending the results of the mapping operations:

```scheme
(define (possible-triads xs ys zs)
  (apply append
         (map (lambda (x)
                (apply append
                       (map (lambda (y)
                              (map (lambda (z) (list x y z))
                                   zs))
                            ys)))
              xs)))
```

Here the innermost `map` over `zs` creates a list of lists. The intermediate `map` uses that result to create a list of lists of lists, which is appended together to get a list of lists. Finally the outermost `map` uses the list of lists provided by the inner two mapping operations to create another list of lists of lists, which is appended together to get the final result as a list of lists.

Note that it is usually not a good idea to use `append` in loops like this; since `append` has linear time complexity by itself, these types of solutions tend to be quadratic or worse.

```
nested-looping.rkt> (possible-triads '(1 2) '(3 4) '(5 6))
'((1 3 5) (1 3 6) (1 4 5) (1 4 6) (2 3 5) (2 3 6) (2 4 5) (2 4 6))
```

Comment: this "generally bad idea" (called `flatMap` or `concatMap` etc) is the basis of Haskell's (et al.) "monadic" treatment of lists (and other things). :) the idea being, since *one* flatMap keeps the list depth as is, so will *any* number of them in sequence. similarly to how since a nested loop (so, 2 loops, one inside the other) produces the values just the same as the one non-nested loop, so will any number of loops nested inside one another, with any total depth ultimately produce the results in sequence, one after another. (which is what "monads" are all about, from one POV)

Comment: (which is like saying almost nothing at all, from an imperative programmer's point of view.)

Answer (score 1):

The python `for` loop doesn't automatically collect its results into lists like `map`, so you don't see the nesting. The equivalent in Scheme is `for-each`, which loops for side effect, not collecting the results. And as in your Python function, you should print the lists in the innermost loop, not return it.

```
(define (possible-triads n1 n2 n3)
  (for-each (lambda (num1)
    (for-each (lambda (num2)
      (for-each (lambda (num3) 
        (display (list num1 num2 num3))) n3)) n2)) n1))
```